# javascript formatDate timezone displaying improperly

Tags: javascript, timezone, formatdatetime

I'm trying to get this working off a branch of someone else's code, but wanted to take a hack at it, and so far, am not sure where the javascript is defined, etc. Not much knowledge here, but from what I'm understanding, this is suboptimal. I've tried a thing or two, but it breaks the whole page.

The TimeZone seems to display incorrectly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8CcP.png

And the Javascript is here: https://github.com/mattgphoto/status/blob/master/script.js

It's something to do with formatDate, but am not sure what of the sections needs to be corrected, or if it's all of them. Would someone be able to help?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following line in **formatDate** function is causing the problem.

```
return y.replace(/(y+)/g, function (v) {
            return x.getFullYear().toString().slice(-v.length)
        });
```

Try replacing that code with

```
return y;
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Thank you for the help, but now the whole page is broken. You can see this in action here: http://status.netstacked.com/

I committed the code to master branch, (not a huge deal) so you can see the edits made here: https://github.com/mattgphoto/status/blob/master/script.js

Comment: I've had to revert the change, as leaving it broken that way for over a day wasn't helpful. If you have other suggestions, let me know.